# Yii2: How to filter fields of a find()->all functions?

Tags: php, arrays, json, controller, yii2

I have to create a JSON with only two fields (**id** and **name**) with data from a table of my database.

I made a function inside my **AnalysisController** file of my Yii2 application:

```
public function actionAnalysis()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $query = Analysis::find()->all();
    return $query;
}
```

Then I tested it with http://localhost:8080/analysis/analysis and it works great. But it returns a lot of fields and I just need **id** and **name** field.

How can modify the **actionAnalysis()** function so it can filter the fields?

Comment: `$query = Analisis::find()->select(['id','name'])->all();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [select()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#select()-detail)

```
$query = Analysis::find()->select(['id','name'])->all();
```

**OR**

If you need an array [asArray()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait#asArray()-detail)

```
$query = Analysis::find()->select(['id','name'])->asArray()->all();
```

**OR**

You want to set up dropdown prefer [column()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail)

```
$query = Analysis::find()->select('name')->indexBy('id')->column();
```